# Why is wc with multiple paths much faster than one by one execution?

Tags: wc

Running `wc` with multiple files is an order of magnitude faster than running it file by file. For example:

```
> time git ls-files -z | xargs -0 wc -l > ../bach.x

real    0m2.765s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m2.531s


> time git ls-files | xargs -I {} wc -l "{}" > ../onebyone.x

real    0m57.832s
user    0m0.156s
sys     0m3.031s
```

*(The repo contains ~10_000 files so xargs runs wc few times, not just once, but that's not material in this context)*

In my naivety I think that `wc` needs to open and process each file so the speedup must be from multi-threading only. However, I've read that there may be some extra files system magic going on here.

Is three file system magic going on here or is it all multi-threading or is it something else?

---

#### Startup penalty

Following up on @muru's comment I can see that a) a single execution is ~8ms and b) running `wc` in a loop scales linearly:

```
> time wc -l ../x.x > /dev/null

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.016s


>  time for run in {1..10}; do wc -l ../x.x; done > /dev/null

real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

> time for run in {1..100}; do wc -l ../x.x; done > /dev/null

real    0m0.689s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.063s
```

Since the multi-file run is much faster per file (*10_000f@3_000ms* => *1f@0.3ms*) there seem to be a (huge?) startup penalty for `wc` which is not related to actually counting the `\n`s.

Comment: Let's say it takes 10ms to just execute `wc`. Multiplying that by 10000 will get you 100s extra just for extra executions involved. It only takes you 55s extra so I suppose the actual time required to execute `wc` is probably much less and helped by caching.

Comment: [`fork`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and [`exec*`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) are costly.

Comment: Er...  your one-by-one output redirection means the output file must be opened and truncated before each `wc` is invoked.  Have you measured appending to the output file instead of replacing it?  That would be closer to the way the file is handled with the multi-file `wc` command.

Comment: @SottoVoce if you're talking about `xargs -I {} wc -l "{}" > ../onebyone.x`, that redirection will be done by the shell before even starting `xargs`.

Comment: Try it without *any* `\n`s. `time wc -l /dev/null` takes me `real 0m0.005s`. 10,000 of those would be 50 seconds. Nothing is doing threading or any other magic.